# Calling a method on a object

Tags: javascript

I would like to log the result of calling a method on a object.

The current script log the result of the function in the property `token` literally I mean the result is the defined function.

What am I doing wrong here? Many thanks!

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        // General Settings
        var 
        ApiSettings = {
            clientId: 'aaa',
            clientSecret: 'bbb',
            token: function () {
                var token;
                $.getJSON(ApiSettings.uriGetToken, processData);
                function processData(data) {
                    token = data.access_token;
                }
                return token;
            }
        }
        ApiSettings.uriGetToken = 'https://ccc.com/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(ApiSettings.clientId) + '&client_secret=' + encodeURIComponent(ApiSettings.clientSecret);

        console.log(ApiSettings);
        console.log(ApiSettings.uriGetToken);
        var test = ApiSettings.token;

        console.log(test);



    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing

```
        token: function () {
            var token;
            $.getJSON(ApiSettings.uriGetToken, processData);
            function processData(data) {
                token = data.access_token;
            }
            return token;
        }
```

with

```
        token: (function () {
            var token;
            $.getJSON(ApiSettings.uriGetToken, processData);
            function processData(data) {
                token = data.access_token;
            }
            return token;
        })()
```

that should execute your function inline.

Alternatively you could pass the URI as a parameter to the token function,

```
       token: function (tokenURI) {
            var token;
            $.getJSON(tokenURI, processData);
            function processData(data) {
                token = data.access_token;
            }
            return token;
        }
```

and then call

```
    ApiSettings.token('https://ccc.com/oauth/token?.......');
```

Comment: thanks for your hit, now i receive an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uriGetToken' of undefined when calling $.getJSON(ApiSettings.uriGetToken, processData);

Comment: any idea how to solve it,i believe it is not related to my original question but I would appreciate your help on this thanks!

Comment: @lostsource That won't work. `ApiSettings.uriGetToken` does not get set until later on.

Comment: thanks for your comment lostsource, I would you solve the issue?

Comment: @RB question was 'Calling a method on a object', if the method fails that's another issue

Comment: you are right I will investigate more thanks for your time on this

Comment: @GibboK .. I added an alternative approach in my original answer, that could also be a solution

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems I think.

1) You need to define the processData function **before** you use it.

```
// $.getJSON(ApiSettings.uriGetToken, processData);
// function processData(data) {
//     token = data.access_token;
// }
// Becomes:
function processData(data) {
    token = data.access_token;
}
$.getJSON(ApiSettings.uriGetToken, processData);
```

2) You need to **call** the token method.

```
// var test = ApiSettings.token;
// Becomes:
var test = ApiSettings.token(); // Note the new brackets.
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out your code out of ready section and it will work. 
I tested it in console of my chrome browser and it works.
Could be some issue with scope.